# Wireless Data Broadcast

Tags: networking, wireless, broadcast, adhoc

I need a simple broadcast model (something like a FM Transmitter, but something which I can control more easily by coding, like WiFi; supported by a laptop or a smartphone) where in one device broadcasts data (to a port number) and any device listening on that port can receive data (the need to connect the devices should not be there, very much like a FM Transmitter/Receiver).

I am open to any new network protocol other than WiFi, a minimum broadcast range of 100M should be present. The security of such a system is not a concern at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Such protocols aren't new, there are WiMax, LTE, GSM etc...
Choose the one you like and purchase the corresponding HW device.